# Add a button to hide keyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uitextview

On a UITextView to hide the keyboard, there is the method:

```
...
    textfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textfield.delegate = self;
....

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;

}
```

but if I want to leave the button "done" to the "return" and add a button to hide the keyboard, how do I?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can assign a toolbar with a button that dismisses the keyboard as the text field's `inputAccessoryView`. A quick example would be,

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:textField action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)] autorelease];
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)] autorelease];
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:barButton];

textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

Comment: I didn't get you. What do you want to call?

Comment: I have a method that saves the text into a database [self saveString];

Comment: You can always change the target-action to call a method that dismisses the keyboard and calls `[self saveString]`.

Comment: this is what I can not do :( you may make a small example? thanks a lot!

Comment: Works well but UIBarButtonItemStyleDone shoule be UIBarButtonSystemItemDone or the button will say Edit.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 2.0 version:

```
//Declared at top of view controller
var accessoryDoneButton: UIBarButtonItem!
let accessoryToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 44))
//Could also be an IBOutlet, I just happened to have it like this
let codeInput = UITextField()

//Configured in viewDidLoad()
self.accessoryDoneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: #selector(self.donePressed(_:)))
self.accessoryToolBar.items = [self.accessoryDoneButton]
self.codeInput.inputAccessoryView = self.accessoryToolBar
```

Swift 4:

```
//Declared at top of view controller
var accessoryDoneButton: UIBarButtonItem!
let accessoryToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
//Could also be an IBOutlet, I just happened to have it like this
let codeInput = UITextField()

//Configured in viewDidLoad()
self.accessoryDoneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.donePressed))
self.accessoryToolBar.items = [self.accessoryDoneButton]
self.codeInput.inputAccessoryView = self.accessoryToolBar

func donePressed() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

[UIToolBar Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIToolbar/barStyle)

['inputAccessoryView' documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputAccessoryView)

Comment: `donePressed` is just a function in your `UIViewController`. I usually resign the active keyboard of the first responder and then pop the view controller off the navigation stack if I so desire.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done ways easier!

I made a custom view in IB, in my viewController.h I just made an `IBOutlet UIView *accessoryView;`, connected them and an `- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard;`

I put in the view a toolbar with a done button, made a connection to the IBAction an wrote:
`[textView resignFirstResponder]` and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    textView.inputAccessoryView = accessoryView;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

But actually that looks a bit strange and non-apple-style… Got an idea?