# How to add Hide keyboard button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, keyboard

How to add hide [image: keyboard] keyboard in iPhone same like as in iPad. I search a lot but didn't get any solution, is it possible to do or not ?

I got only these options:

```
UIReturnKeyDefault,
UIReturnKeyGo,
UIReturnKeyGoogle,
UIReturnKeyJoin,
UIReturnKeyNext,
UIReturnKeyRoute,
UIReturnKeySearch,
UIReturnKeySend,
UIReturnKeyYahoo,
UIReturnKeyDone,
UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
```

Comment: See the 1st answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079815/trying-to-add-done-button-to-numeric-keyboard?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a button to hide keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179534/add-a-button-to-hide-keyboard)

Comment: I want to change in keyboard buttons,not a toolbar button above the keyboard.

Comment: You can't. There is no API to customize a keyboard. You either add the `inputAccessoryView` or you create a totally custom keyboard and use it as the `inputView` of the text field or text view.