# How to create "Close" toolbar or button that will appear with the keyboard when typing text in a textView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, textview

all! I have a textView. When I want to type a text, a keyboard appears. And when I press a return key, text is going to the new line. It is standard function of a textView in Xcode. And I want it to be so. But in order to close a keyboard I want the toolbar with a button "Close "upon the keyboard appear. How can I do that?Can you help with code or give links to some good tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

You accomplish this by setting an `inputAccessoryView`.

The easiest thing would either be a `UIView` with a `UIButton` in it or a `UIToolbar` with a `UIBarButtonItem` in it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179534/add-a-button-to-hide-keyboard) has some example code to do exactly this.